# SR Suntour XCM v3 forks Headset

Tags: fork, headset

Currently building a new mountain bike and for the time being I'm using the old forks until I buy some new ones.

My question is how do I find out what type of headset I need? Because from my understanding there are quite a few different types.

Update: I have uploaded a couple of images. It looks to be integrated, as there are bearings/cups already in the frame and threadless. The steerer/stem width is 1 1/8th.

I think that solves my question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Theres more than one fork sold under that name - you should get the serial number and put it in the search bar on Suntour's website. Also, re-using forks may be troublesome depending on if the fork steer tube is long enough among other factors.

Comment: Thanks @Batman - I will take a look. The fork steerer tube is long enough, I need a few spacers at the top to make it fit.

Comment: I'm still unsure if I need semi or fully integrated?

Comment: It actually could be conventional, having looked around.

Comment: I'm looking at buying either of these:
http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/hope-conventional-ec34-headset/rp-prod19877

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/fsa-orbit-mx-headset/rp-prod2217

Comment: Neither of those would work with a semi-integrated head tube. EC34 is a conventional headset. What is the frame?

Comment: I've just uploaded the only picture that partially shows the frame - it's a Carerra Vulcan XC.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few factors to choosing a headset, primarily frame related:

- Does the frame require a threaded (1") or threadless head set?
- What is the headtube/ steerer type (1.5 straight, tapered, 1 1/8 straight)
- Is the headset integrated (cups sit within the frame)?

Deciding if a fork will fit is a bit easier, is the steerer the correct length (it can be longer, you can use spacers above or below the stem for fit) and is it compatible? You can get headsets that interface some head tubes to steerer they are tapered steerer in 1.5 head tube or 1 1/8 steerer in tapered head tube.

Firstly identify what headset you need first and work from there. [Cane Creeks](http://www.canecreek.com/headset-fit-finder) headset finder is a good start.

Comment: Thanks @DWGKNZ - very helpful. I will find out the answers and get back to you. If I'm unsure I will post some pictures.

Comment: Updated my question with a few images.